# Heroku Legacy Platform Sunsetting. How to migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, migration

While updating my client's application on Heroku, I received the following warning message:

```
 The Heroku Legacy Platform API will be Sunset on April 15th 2017. Please update your client access or the Heroku CLI to the latest version. See https://blog.heroku.com/sunsetting_heroku_s_legacy_platform_api_v2 for more details.
```

The link it provides explains why its sunsetting but not how to migrate to remove this warning message. The links that site take you to the API documentation but I couldn't find any docs on migration from v2 to v3 Heroku API.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, updating heroku toolbelt wasn't working. Removing the link to the repository and then following the steps to install heroku again in the link I've provided fixed my problem.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli